# Calling C# from Dafny: unable to find certain names in System.Net (.NET core 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dafny

I am trying to do a simple UDP networking example in Dafny by calling `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient` in C# externally. I've defined `:extern` classes and methods in Dafny that I've implemented in a C# file that calls `UdpClient` to send packets. However, I am facing the following issue, in that the Dafny compiler complains that it cannot find `UdpClient`, among other things, in the `System.Net` namespace.

Here is the code that I am using, which is based on an old version of [Ironfleet](https://github.com/microsoft/Ironclad/tree/da25a3c3b46117fc97ff073e20514895d6411cae/ironfleet/src/Dafny/Distributed/Common/Native).

###### `Io.dfy`

```cs
include "NativeTypes.dfy"

module{:extern "NativeIO"} NativeIO {
import opened NativeTypes

class OkState
{
  constructor{:axiom} () requires false
  function{:axiom} ok():bool reads this
}

class HostEnvironment
{
  ghost var ok:OkState

  constructor{:axiom} () requires false

  predicate Valid()
    reads this
  {
    true
  }
}

datatype EndPoint = EndPoint(addr:seq<byte>, port:uint16)

class{:extern "IPEndPoint"} IPEndPoint
{
  ghost var env:HostEnvironment
  function{:extern} Address():seq<byte> reads this
  function{:extern} Port():uint16 reads this
  constructor{:extern} () requires false

  method{:extern} GetAddress() returns(addr:array<byte>)
    ensures fresh(addr)
    ensures addr[..] == Address()
    ensures addr.Length == 4      // Encoding current IPv4 assumption

  method{:axiom} GetPort() returns (port: uint16)
    ensures port == Port()

  static method{:axiom} Construct(ipAddress:array<byte>, port:uint16, ghost env:HostEnvironment) returns(ok:bool, ep:IPEndPoint)
    requires env.Valid()
    modifies env.ok
    ensures  env.ok.ok() == ok
    ensures  ok ==> fresh(ep) && ep.env == env && ep.Address() == ipAddress[..] && ep.Port() == port

  static method{:extern} DnsResolve(name:seq<uint16>) returns (resolved_name:seq<uint16>)
}

function MaxPacketSize() : int { 0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF }

class{:extern "UdpClient"} UdpClient
{
  ghost var env:HostEnvironment
  function{:axiom} LocalEndPoint():EndPoint reads this
  function{:axiom} IsOpen():bool reads this
  constructor{:axiom} () requires false

  static method{:axiom} Construct(localEP:IPEndPoint, ghost env:HostEnvironment) returns(ok:bool, udp:UdpClient?)

  method{:axiom} Close() returns(ok:bool)

  method{:axiom} Receive(timeLimit:int32) returns(ok:bool, timedOut:bool, remote:IPEndPoint, buffer:array<byte>)

  method{:axiom} Send(remote:IPEndPoint, buffer:array<byte>) returns(ok:bool)
}

}
```

###### `IoNative.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UClient = System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient;
using IEndPoint = System.Net.IPEndPoint;


namespace NativeIO {

public partial class HostConstants
{
    public static uint NumCommandLineArgs()
    {
        return (uint)System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length;
    }

    public static ushort[] GetCommandLineArg(ulong i)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll(System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[i].ToCharArray(), c => (ushort)c);
    }
}

public partial class IPEndPoint
{
    internal IEndPoint endpoint;
    internal IPEndPoint(IEndPoint endpoint) { this.endpoint = endpoint; }

    public byte[] GetAddress()
    {
        // no exceptions thrown:
        return (byte[])(endpoint.Address.GetAddressBytes().Clone());
    }

    public ushort GetPort()
    {
        // no exceptions thrown:
        return (ushort)endpoint.Port;
    }

    public static void Construct(byte[] ipAddress, ushort port, out bool ok, out IPEndPoint? endpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            ipAddress = (byte[])(ipAddress.Clone());
            endpoint = new IPEndPoint(new IEndPoint(new System.Net.IPAddress(ipAddress), port));
            ok = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
            endpoint = null;
            ok = false;
        }
    }

    // DnsResolve is a Dafny function, which must be deterministic, so remember lookup results
    private static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> dns =
        new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static Dafny.ISequence<ushort> DnsResolve(Dafny.ISequence<ushort> name)
    {
        var str_name = new String(Array.ConvertAll(name.Elements, c => (char)c));
        try
        {
            if (dns.ContainsKey(str_name))
            {
                return Dafny.Sequence<ushort>.FromArray(Array.ConvertAll(dns[str_name].ToCharArray(), c => (ushort)c));
            }
            foreach (var addr in System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(str_name).AddressList)
            {
                if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    dns.Add(str_name, addr.ToString());
                    return Dafny.Sequence<ushort>.FromArray(Array.ConvertAll(addr.ToString().ToCharArray(), c => (ushort)c));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: DNS lookup failed for " + str_name);
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
            dns.Add(str_name, str_name);
            return name;
        }
        System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: could not find IPv4 address for " + str_name);
        dns.Add(str_name, str_name);
        return name;
    }
}

public struct Packet {
    public IEndPoint ep;
    public byte[] buffer;
}

public partial class UdpClient
{
    internal UClient client;
    internal Thread sender;
    internal Thread receiver;
    internal ConcurrentQueue<Packet> send_queue;
    internal ConcurrentQueue<Packet> receive_queue;

    internal UdpClient(UClient client) { 
      this.client = client;
      this.send_queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>();
      this.receive_queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Packet>();
      this.sender = new Thread(SendLoop);
      this.sender.Start();
      this.receiver = new Thread(ReceiveLoop);
      this.receiver.Start();
    }

    private static bool ShouldIgnoreException(Exception e)
    {
      if (e is SocketException se) {
          if (se.ErrorCode == 10054 /* WSAECONNRESET */) {
            return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
    }

    public static void Construct(IPEndPoint localEP, out bool ok, out UdpClient? udp)
    {
        try
        {
            udp = new UdpClient(new UClient(localEP.endpoint));
            udp.client.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192 * 100;
            ok = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
            udp = null;
            ok = false;
        }
    }

    public void Close(out bool ok)
    {
        try
        {
            client.Close();
            ok = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (ShouldIgnoreException(e)) {
                ok = true;
            }
            else {
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
                ok = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Receive(int timeLimit, out bool ok, out bool timedOut, out IPEndPoint? remote, out byte[]? buffer)
    {
        buffer = null;
        remote = null;
        try
        {
            Packet packet;
            bool dequeued = this.receive_queue.TryDequeue(out packet);
            if (!dequeued) {
                if (timeLimit == 0) {
                    ok = true;
                    timedOut = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Going to sleep unexpectedly!");
                    Thread.Sleep(timeLimit);  // REVIEW: This is very conservative, but shouldn't matter, since we don't use this path
                    Receive(0, out ok, out timedOut, out remote, out buffer);
                }
            } else {
//                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Dequeued a packet from: " + packet.ep.Address + " port " + packet.ep.Port);
                timedOut = false;
                remote = new IPEndPoint(packet.ep);
                buffer = new byte[packet.buffer.Length];
                Array.Copy(packet.buffer, buffer, packet.buffer.Length);
                ok = true;
            }     
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (ShouldIgnoreException(e)) {
                ok = true;
                timedOut = true;
            }
            else {
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
                timedOut = false;
                ok = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReceiveLoop() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Packet packet = new Packet();
                packet.buffer = client.Receive(ref packet.ep);
                this.receive_queue.Enqueue(packet);
                //System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Enqueued a packet from: " + packet.ep.Address);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (!ShouldIgnoreException(e)) {
                    System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SendLoop() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Packet packet;
                bool dequeued = this.send_queue.TryDequeue(out packet);
                if (dequeued) {                
                      int nSent = client.Send(packet.buffer, packet.buffer.Length, packet.ep);
                      if (nSent != packet.buffer.Length) {
                          //throw new Exception("only sent " + nSent + " of " + packet.buffer.Length + " bytes");
                          System.Console.Error.Write("only sent " + nSent + " of " + packet.buffer.Length + " bytes");
                      }                
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (!ShouldIgnoreException(e)) {
                    System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Send(IPEndPoint remote, byte[] buffer)
    {
        Packet p = new Packet();
        p.ep = remote.endpoint;
        p.buffer = new byte[buffer.Length];
        Array.Copy(buffer, p.buffer, buffer.Length);
        this.send_queue.Enqueue(p);
        return true; // ok
    }

}


}
```

###### `IoTest.dfy` (main function)

```cs
include "Io.dfy"

module Main {
import opened NativeIO
import opened NativeTypes

method {:main} Main(ghost env: HostEnvironment)
    requires env.ok.ok()
    modifies env.ok
{
    var ipAddress := new byte[4];
    ipAddress[0] := 0x7F;
    ipAddress[1] := 0x00;
    ipAddress[2] := 0x00;
    ipAddress[3] := 0x01;
    var ok, localEndpoint := IPEndPoint.Construct(ipAddress, 5000, env);
    var client: UdpClient?;
    ok, client := UdpClient.Construct(localEndpoint, env);

    var port := localEndpoint.GetPort();
    print port, "\n";
}

}
```

And here is the output I get when I try to compile  `IoTest.cs` and `IoNative.cs` together using the Dafny compiler.

```
$ dafny IoTest.dfy IoNative.cs

Dafny program verifier finished with 2 verified, 0 errors
Wrote textual form of target program to IoTest.cs
Errors compiling program into IoTest
(8,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(9,30): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IPEndPoint' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(2,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Sockets' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(120,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SocketException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

(49,68): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IPAddress' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(73,34): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dns' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(75,43): error CS0103: The name 'AddressFamily' does not exist in the current context
```

I know that these do indeed exist in the System.Net namespace in my .NET installation, because when I compile and run the C# file alone with `dotnet`, it works. What might be causing this discrepancy between the Dafny compiler and the `dotnet` compiler?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some code?

Comment: This kind of thing happens in C# compiler when the assembly (dll) file is not resolved. A typical case is running build without prior restore. Are you able to provide the exact build commands that the tool issues under the hood? It could be that it's looking for assemblies in a different directory than where they are output with `restore`. Or the restore step could be silently failing.

Comment: I have added some code to my question. I think my main issue is that I'm unfamiliar with .NET as well as the Dafny compiler specifics, so I'm not sure where to look for the build commands Dafny uses.

Comment: A more modern dafny library does some io here. https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/tree/master/src/FileIO